# Change annotation image size in MapBox iOS SDK

Tags: ios, mapbox

I have several annotations in a map view. I want these annotations to look smaller when the zoom level increases. How can I do that?

Currently I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35229297/3385517) to other question who says that you can update the image corresponding to a annotation, but it doesn't explain how to do that. If I knew how to update the images, I could solve my problem listening for zoom level changes and updating the images of all the annotations currently in the map. Is that the expected solution?

Answer (score 0):

Removing and replacing the annotations is one option.

Another option is to use the Runtime Styling API, which allows you to dynamically style your map based on user interactions. You could create an MGLCircleStyleLayer or MGLSymbolStyleLayer that resizes the circles based on zoom level. You would have to add interaction to the circles, but it would give you a little more control over how your annotations appear. [This example](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/runtime-multiple-annotations/) could help you to get started.

In order to change the radius of the circle layer based on the zoom level, you could do something like:

```
circles.circleRadius = MGLStyleValue(interpolationMode: .exponential, 
                                     cameraStops: [5: MGLStyleValue(rawValue: 6), 
                                                   18: MGLStyleValue(rawValue: 0.5)], 
                                     options: nil)
```

For the symbol layer (the lighthouse icons), you would adjust the `iconScale` property.